# Can only add single image to Ubercart product

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ubercart

I'm using Ubercart on Drupal 7, pretty basic install. (IMCE, WYSIWYG, Ubercart)
However, I am unable to upload multiple images when creating a product node although Ubercart says multiple image support should work out-of-the-box.

The image field is the default uc_product_image.

[image]

I have Lightbox enabled and image field is configured to allow for unlimited image uploads.

[image]

Still, the single-upload widget is shown that allows me to only upload.. a single image.

[image]

I have checked the permissions (all good) and the Ubercart image support status (green light: "Product image support has been automatically configured by Ubercart.")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only try to upload one and press the button "Upload".
Probably you already got the solution.

[image: Multiple Node Images]

Comment: You can imagine how stupid i feel. I should really stop doing this 'til 6 in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: Happened the same to me, it's Ubercart GUI's fault